# Is there a way to delay Docker ONBUILD instructions to a future child image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there a way to extend a base image that has `ONBUILD` instructions, but just forward the `ONBUILD` instructions to future child images rather than executing them? It'd be something like

```
FROM scratch as base
ONBUILD do stuff

FROM base as intermediate
# don't "do stuff" yet

FROM intermediate as target_1
# "do stuff" *now*

FROM base as target_2
# also "do stuff" now
```

Basically this allows building "onbuild" style images using multi-stage builds, and thus potentially more efficiently. Does anything like this exist in Docker? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how this makes sense in the context of a multi stage build. The onbuild is used to run commands in a future build in a different environment. With the multi stage build, you can just put everything in the same Dockerfile.

Comment: In my scenario I'm building a base image meant to be used by other users, so I can't just put everything in one Dockerfile, I have to use ONBUILD. At the same time, for building this base image its convenient to use a multi-stage build to improve caching.

Comment: The only part you would want the ONBUILD steps on then would be the final image you ship to other users. There wouldn't be multiple ONBUILD sections throughout the multi-stage build in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot delay the processing of ONBUILD. It will run on the next child image.

Note that I tend to recommend against ONBUILD for all but very specialized use cases because having steps performed during your build that are not listed in your Dockerfile tends to confuse users. Your use case may be more appropriate to have the users run the commands directly in their Dockerfile instead of forcing it on them from the parent image.